Firebase Emulator Consistently Uses Random and Already Occupied Ports Despite Configuration
I'm facing an issue with Firebase local serving. It seems Firebase is using a different port to serve the server locally. The worst part is that it's a random port every time, and each time it's occupied. I've closed all processes, and most importantly, I've set a specific port 5001 in my Firebase configurations. However, when I run firebase serve or firebase deploy, it serves on a different port (always over 8000). Has anyone encountered this issue, or am I doing something wrong?
Here's my firebase.json configuration:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "server"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "server",
    "runtime": "nodejs18",
    "port": "5001",
    "ignore": [
      "public/**",
      "src/**"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    }
  }
}

I keep getting messages like:
Serving at port 8783

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8783

And every time it's a different port.

If you have a problem with the way the Firebase CLI works, you should file a bug with your steps to reproduce the issue on GitHub.

I think it's something with my config rather than a bug though.

What have you done to debug your configuration?  Try starting from a clean configuration that the CLI creates for you, then slowly add in your customizations to find out which one might be causing the problem.  Your question (or bug report) can then show specifically what you did that caused the problem.

I ran firebase debug but it doesn't tell me anything that I could interpret. I reinstalled dependencies, firebase-tools, updated everything and so on. It all only gets me more confused to be frank. I shall start with a clean configuration as you suggest. Any tip on what would I do? Just start the project all over or only remove all config files  and modules?

I don't have any suggestions other than what I already said. Start simple, slowly add and test as you go.
